# Nongreedy Regex with Repetition

Tags: python, regex, string, non-greedy

I am using the following regex: 
    `((FFD8FF).+?((FFD9)(?:(?!FFD8).)*))`

I need to do the following with regex:

Find `FFD8FF`

Find the last `FFD9`that comes before the next `FFD8FF`

Stop at the last `FFD9` and not include any content after

What I've got does what I need *except* it finds and keeps any junk after the last FFD9. How can I get it to jump back to the last `FFD9`?

Here's the string that I'm searching with this expression:

> asdfasdfasasdaFFD8FFasdfalsjdflajsdfljasdfasdfasdfasdfFFD9asdflasdflasdfFFD9asdfasdfFFD8FFasdfalsjdflajsdfljasdfasdfasdfasdfFFD9

Thanks a lot for your help.

More info:

I have a list of start and end values I need to search for (FFD8FF and FFD9 are just one pair). They are in a list. Because of this, I'm using r.compile to dynamically create the expression in a for loop that goes through the different values. I have the following code, but it is returning 0 matches:

`regExp = re.compile("FD8FF(?:[^F]|F(?!FD8FF))*FFD9")
matchObj = re.findall(regExp, contents)`

In the above code, I'm just trying to use the plain regex without even getting the values from the list (that would look like this):

`regExp = re.compile(typeItem[0] + "(?:[^" + typeItem[0][0] + "]|" + typeItem[0][0] + "(?!" + typeItem[0] + "))*" + typeItem[1])`

Any other ideas why there aren't any matches?

EDIT:

I figured out that I forgot to include flags. Flags are now included to ignore case and multiline. I now have

`regExp = re.compile(typeItem[0] + "(?:[^" + typeItem[0][0] + "]|" + typeItem[0][0] + "(?!" + typeItem[0] + "))*" + typeItem[1],re.M|re.I)`

Although now I'm getting a memory error. Is there any way to make this more efficient? I am using the expression to search hundreds of thousands of lines (using the `findall` expression above)

Comment: so whats your expected output ?

Comment: If the problem with your pattern is that it finds garbage after the last `FFD9`, why did you give us an example input that has nothing after the last `FFD9`? That makes it very hard to see the problem…

Comment: @Kasra Matchobj should be returned containing the FFD8FF...FFD9 value in a tuple

Comment: Also, after your edit… when you "figured out that I forgot to include flags", what exactly did you change? What actual pattern and flags are you now using? What input are you using it on that gives a memory error? More generally: just post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of trying to describe your example in text. (That includes pasting the traceback instead of just saying "getting a memory error".)

Comment: @abarnert the example does have garbage after the first FFD8FF...FFD9 pair.

Comment: @jbenes: Your rule 3 is "Stop at the last FFD9". When I test your pattern in [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/W-D96pipt6lxWax5), the first match ends in the `FFD9` about half-way through, and the second stops at the end. If I add some garbage at the end, the second match doesn't include it. So I'm not seeing the problem you describe.

Comment: @jbenes do you mean `FFD8FF` instead of `FFD8DD`? Otherwise your example will not make sense.

Comment: @abarnert my apologies. It should be FFD8FF for the third rule. simonzack caught the mistake

Comment: @jbenes: Don't try to clarify the question in a comment, edit the question so it contains enough (and correct!) information.

Comment: Also, even with that correction… look at the linked Debuggex. There are two matches, and both are stopping after an `FD8FF…FFD9`. (I don't know why you left the first `F` out of the pattern, but that's obviously trivial to fix.) So… again, what's the actual problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

an easy way is to use this:

```
FFD8FF(?:[^F]|F(?!FD8FF))*FFD9
```

explanation:

```
FFD8FF
(?:     # this group describe the allowed content between the "anchors" 
    [^F]        # all that is not a "F"
  |             # OR
    F(?!FD8FF)  # a "F" not followed by "FD8FF"
)*              # repeat (greedy)
FFD9            # until the last FFD9 before FFD8FF
```

Even if a greedy quantifier is used for the group, the regex engine will backtrack to find the last "FFD9" substring.

If you want to ensure that FFD8FF is present, you can add a lookahead at the end of the pattern:

```
FFD8FF(?:[^F]|F(?!FD8FF))*FFD9(?=.*?FFD8FF)
```

You can optimize this pattern by emulating an atomic group that will limit the backtracking and allows to use quantifier inside the group:

```
FFD8FF(?:(?=([^F]+|F(?!FD8FF)))\1)*FFD9
```

This trick uses the fact that the content of a lookahead is naturally atomic once the closing parenthesis reached. So if you enclose a group inside a lookahead with a capture group inside, you only have to put the backreference after to obtain an "atom" (an indivisable substring). 
When the regex engine need to backtrack, it will backtrack atom by atom instead of character by character that is much faster.

If you need a capture group before this trick, don't forget to update the number of the backreference, examples:

```
(FFD8FF(?:(?=([^F]+|F(?!FD8FF)))\2)*FFD9)

(FFD8FF((?:(?=([^F]+|F(?!FD8FF)))\3)*)FFD9)
```

working example:

```
>>> import re
>>> yourstr = 'asdfasdfasasdaFFD8FFasdfalsjdflajsdfljasdfasdfasdfasdfFFD9asdflasdflasdfFFD9asdfasdfFFD8FFasdfalsjdflajsdfljasdfasdfasdfasdfFFD9'
>>> p = re.compile(r'(FFD8FF((?:(?=([^F]+|F(?!FD8FF)))\3)*)FFD9)(?=.*?FFD8FF)')
>>> re.findall(p, yourstr)
[('FFD8FFasdfalsjdflajsdfljasdfasdfasdfasdfFFD9asdflasdflasdfFFD9', 'asdfalsjdflajsdfljasdfasdfasdfasdfFFD9asdflasdflasdf', 'D9asdflasdflasdf')]
```

variant:

```
(FFD8FF((?:(?=(F(?!FD8FF)[^F]*|[^F]+))\3)*)FFD9)(?=.*?FFD8FF)
```

Comment: This worked for small strings, but can this be made more efficient to work on large strings without a memory error?

Comment: @jbenes: I will give you the same pattern optimized.

Comment: The `\1` seems to be giving me some kind of problem. When I print the regex being used, it prints, `FFD8FF(?:(?=([^F]+|F(?!FD8FF))))*FFD9`

(the `\1` is actually a weird box symbol displayed in my terminal)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I like your approach better than mine. Don't you think `((FFD8FF)((?!FFD8FF).)+(FFD9))` would be clearer as an unoptimized example?

Comment: Using `r'......'` worked in getting rid of the weird parse error, but now I'm only getting very short string matches (9b29, 2129ab4, and others) that aren't even present in the body of the values I'm searching. Any thoughts?

Comment: @simonzack: I don't think there is one expression more clear than the other. The two have their inconveniant, mine is efficient if the distance between the last FFD9 and FFD8FF is not to long (otherwise the backtracking is terrible), when yours must test a lookahead for each character, but don't have to backtrack since you use a non-greedy quantifier.

Comment: @jbenes: yes, these strings are the content of the last capture from the group 1, you must ignore them, you only need the whole match. in this case enclose the whole pattern between parenthesis and replace `\1` with `\2`.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte even using a double `\\` and not using the raw input causes the same problem. Instead of returning `FFD8FF` to `FFD9` and everything in between, the odd values are returned (they don't appear anywhere in the body that is being searched)


I used `\2` and got `sre_constants.error: bogus escape: '\2'`

Comment: @jbenes: omg. I will add to my answer a full working example, wait a minute.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not restricted to one regexp by your application's architecture, break it down into steps:

1. You want to break up the text in units that begin at each `FFD8FF`. Just use non-greedy search that ends just before the next `FFD8FF`:  `re.findall(r"FFD8FF.*?(?=FFD8FF)", contents)`. (This uses look-ahead, which is in my opinion overused; but it lets you save the final FFD8FF for the next string.)
2. You then want to trim each such string so that it ends at the *last* `FFD9`. Easiest way to do this is with greedy search:  `re.search(r"^.*FFD9", part)`. Like this:

   ```
   for part in re.findall(r"FFD8FF.*?(?=FFD8FF)", contents):
       print(re.search(r"^.*FFD9", part).group(0))
   ```

Simple, maintainable and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
>>> re.search(r'((FFD8FF).+?(FFD9))(?:((?!FFD9).)+FFD8FF)', s).groups()
('FFD8FFasdfalsjdflajsdfljasdfasdfasdfasdfFFD9asdflasdflasdfFFD9',
 'FFD8FF',
 'FFD9',
 'f')
```

The second part just searches for a string not containing `FFD9` that ends with `FFD8FF`.

It includes your search components, so you can still substitute them in your regex. However for something rather complicated like this I would avoid regex.

btw, thanks for posting a regex question that is high-quality and not the usual spam.